# In Java how do i structure a for loop to find me the max and min of ten values entered. I am currently recieveing not output from this program

Tags: java, for-loop

What I am trying to do is receive ten values from the user to the tenth decimal place. I then want to find the max and min value, and display only them. I've tried many different configurations, this one having the most logic, but am still unable to get any kind of output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab5b     
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        for (int counter = 0; counter <= 10; counter++ )
        {
            double currentMin = in.nextDouble();

                while (in.hasNextDouble())
                {
                    double input = in.nextDouble();
                    if (input < currentMin)
                    {
                        currentMin = input;
                    }
                }

            double currentMax = in.nextDouble();

                while (in.hasNextDouble())
                {
                    double input = in.nextDouble();
                    if (input > currentMax)
                    {
                        currentMax = input;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(currentMax);
                System.out.print(currentMin);

        }   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of possible solutions...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMaxForLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double current;

        System.out.println("Enter 10 double values:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1) + ". -> ");
            current = input.nextDouble();
            if(current < min)
                min = current;
            else if(current > max)
                max = current;
        }
        System.out.println("Min: " + min);
        System.out.println("Max: " + max);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I would simplify your code. You could use [`Math.min(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28double,%20double%29) and [`Math.max(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28double,%20double%29). The first value is `0` so you want the test to be `<` (not `<=`) and you could check for the `nextDouble()` condition in the loop condition. That might look something like

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int values = 10;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
for (int counter = 0; counter < values && in.hasNextDouble(); counter++) {
    double v = in.nextDouble();
    min = Math.min(min, v);
    max = Math.max(max, v);
}
System.out.println("min: " + min);
System.out.println("max: " + max);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is stuck in an infinite loop in the first while loop
To fix this, put in a break statement.

```
if (input < currentMin){
    currentMin = input;
    break;
}
```

And also in the other if statement.

```
if (input > currentMax){
    currentMax = input;
    break;
}
```

Because else it always keeps asking for new input in the first while loop.

Also change:

```
System.out.print(currentMin);
```

to

```
System.out.println(currentMin);
```

for a new line.

But still if i input

5
7
4
2
6
it says:
Max = 6.0
Min = 4.0
because it does not take 7 into concideration for currentMax and 2 not for currentMin because it exited that while loop already.